# Parsing a JSON file and adding it to a model

Tags: python, json, django

I'm using Django (written a script here). I'm trying to parse a JSON file and add it to a model I've created . However, I'm getting this weird error that I'm unable to figure out !

```
import os
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] =  "json_api.settings"
import json
from api.models import User_details

with open('./static/test.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

r = User_details.objects.create(uid=int(data["User"]["id"]) ,
                                premium=bool(data["User"]["premium"]) ,
                                last_filled=data["LastFilled"] ,
                                trip_mode=data["Trip_Mode"] , 
                                odometer=int(data["Params"]["Odometer"]), 
                                fuel=int(data["Params"]["Fuel"]), 
                                tirep_fl=int(data["Params"]["Fuel"]["frontLeft"]),
                                tirep_fr=int(data["Params"]["TireP"]["frontRight"]),
                                tirep_bl=int(data["Params"]["TireP"]["backLeft"]),
                                tirep_br=int(data["Params"]["TireP"]["backRight"]))
r.save()
```

JSON File :

```
{
    "User": {
        "id": "123456678923",
        "premium": "False"
    },
    "LastFilled": "16/02/02-00:45:32",
    "Trip_Mode": "Disabled",
    "Params": {
        "Odometer": "12345",
        "Fuel": "0.78",
        "TireP": {
            "frontLeft": "32",
            "frontRight": "29",
            "backLeft": "24",
            "backRight": "26"
        }
    }
}
```

Error :

```
(env) saru95   $   python import_data.py
  File "import_data.py", line 19
    r.save()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EDIT :

After adding the missing parenthesis and running `python import_data.py` i get the following error :

```
(env) saru95   $   python import_data.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_data.py", line 4, in <module>
    from api.models import User_details
  File "/Users/sarthakmunshi/Desktop/django-cookbook/json_api/api/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class User_details(models.Model):
  File "/Users/sarthakmunshi/Desktop/django-cookbook/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Users/sarthakmunshi/Desktop/django-cookbook/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/sarthakmunshi/Desktop/django-cookbook/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: That's a different error already, don't try to stuff all the errors you get into one question. Better triple-check your code and then ask another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing

```
import os
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] =  "json_api.settings"
```

by

```
from json_api.wsgi import *
```

where `json_api` is my project name . Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

You're missing close parens for the `int` calls from `fuel` and all four of the `tirep_*` values.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot lots of closing parentheses:

```
fuel=int(data["Params"]["Fuel"]), 
tirep_fl=int(data["Params"]["Fuel"]["frontLeft"]),
tirep_fr=int(data["Params"]["TireP"]["frontRight"]),
tirep_bl=int(data["Params"]["TireP"]["backLeft"]),
tirep_br=int(data["Params"]["TireP"]["backRight"])
```